# Вижу уведомление о собственных правках, ждущих в очереди

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, правки, очередь-проверок, описание-метки

Вижу «лампочку», сигнализирующую о непустой очереди правок (на Мете):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, если нажать на нее, то во всех трех категориях ноль доступных для проверки правок. Поскольку я только что предложил правку описаний меток, предполагаю, что именно её я и вижу. Однако, у меня висит три неподтвержденных правки: на одну метку только краткое описание, на другую полное и краткое.

Добавил еще одну правку краткого описания, теперь «лампочка» показывает число 3 — ровно столько, сколько у меня неподтвержденных правок описаний меток.

**Баг: собственные неподтвержденные правки описаний меток включаются в число неподтвержденных правок, которое показывается пользователю на специальной кнопке рядом с «очередь проверок».**

На момент обнаружения у меня 1876 репутации. Привилегия «Принятие описания меток»
как раз недавно получена.

Comment: насколько я понимаю, это общая длина очереди проверок, единая для всех. посмотреть, сколько из этих проверок относятся к той или иной очереди можно, например, под «анонимусом».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Неа, эта кнопка показывает только неподтвержденные правки. Вероятно, это сделано для того, чтобы максимально ускорить их проверку. Остальные очереди в счетчик не включаются, я проверял.

Comment: на *мете* — может быть. на основном сайте, насколько я вижу, показывает длину **всех** очередей проверок в сумме.

Comment: Странно, что несмотря на всевозможные уверения `by-design` и `значение кэшируется`, бОльшую часть времени счетчик ведет себя адекватно. Но иногда (на текущий момент времени например) у меня стабильно показывает `1` при пустой очереди, сколько не обновляй страницу.

Comment: @alexolut потому что где-то есть проверка, которую вы уже обработали, но нужны ещё проверки от других людей. Вам эта проверка не видна, но она всё ещё активна.

Comment: @NickVolynkin вероятно, что так, но, черт побери, хотелось бы сделать это очевидным для проверяющего.

Comment: @alexolut а сейчас сколько показывает?

Comment: @NickVolynkin сейчас уже пусто. Но `1` держалась довольно долго, обычно такого не происходит.

Comment: @alexolut у меня 24 на кнопке, а внутри 16+3+1. Вроде похоже на запаздывающий кэш.

Comment: @NickVolynkin когда он запаздывает для ненулевых значений не так обидно. Т.к. всё равно есть что проверять. А когда стабильно (довольного долго) рисует отличное от нуля значение, а внутри пусто - это несколько обескураживает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как правильно заметил [@alexander](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178576/alexander-barakin), индикатор отображает общее количество элементов в очереди проверки для пользователя получившего привилегию [инструментов модератора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). Все данные (включая сам индикатор), представленные в очереди проверки, несут информационный характер, а не призывают к действию.

В общем, можно говорить, что индикатор отображает то, насколько  пользователи с большой репутацией, то есть те, которые управляют сообществом, вовлечены в процесс и достаточно ли таких участников. Таким образом, если цифра растет день ото дня то, скорее всего, что-то не так "в нашем королевстве". Если количество элементов в очереди минимально, то в сообществе достаточно участников, которые определились с тем, каким они хотят видеть сайт.

---

Дополнительные ссылки на Meta Stack Exchange.

- [Notification for reviews shows way too much](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230742/).
- [Notify users of possible reviews on toolbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/).

Comment: Спасибо, понял, почитаю.

Comment: Окей, но тогда контрпредложение: показывать фон разными цветами в зависимости от того, есть ли в очереди то, что может обработать текущий пользователь. Это избавит от ситуации, когда человек заходит в список проверок, а этот список пуст. (Проблема нерелевантна для en.SO, потому что там _всегда_ большие очереди.)

Comment: Технически, на сколько я понимаю, такие запросы получаются очень "дорогими". Даже общее число кэшируется.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky так в очереде правок показываются же кол-ва по каждой категории? На общего индикатора достаточно их просто суммировать

Comment: @korytoff Возможно. Я не смотрел код выборки, но во время общения с коллегами, да и на MSO, не раз говорилось о том, что это и ресурсозатратно (тяжелый запрос), и идеологически не верно.

Answer (score 5):

Судя по всему, этот счетчик действительно показывает актуальное количество элементов в очереди проверки для конкретного пользователя...но только до достижения пользователем 2000 репутации. После этого счетчик "ломается" и начинает показывать общее закэшированное значение, включая

- посты самого пользователя, по которым инициирована проверка
- проверки, которые текущий пользователь уже завершил, но по которым нужны дополнительные голоса
- проверки, инициированные текущим пользователем (например, поставленные напрямую флаги или голоса за закрытие)
- пропущенные проверки

... который на самой странице ревью не видно.

Почему счетчик ломается на 2000? Скорее всего из-за того, что на большом enSO до 2000 репутации пользователь видит всего 3 очереди (Triage/Late/First), которые почти всегда пусты.

А после 2000 он начинает видеть еще три, включая вечно забитую Close Votes (9000 на данный момент). Фильтровать 9000 постов для каждого пользователя ради мелкого счетчика на каждой странице - накладно. И где-то в коде вписан if:

```
if (rep < 2000)
{
    посчитать и показать личный счетчик по всем доступным очередям
}
else // perf hack!
{
    показать общий закэшированный счетчик
}
```

По крайней мере он поломался на 2000 у меня, у @LEQADA и у @korytoff. Хотя до 2000 работал идеально.

Comment: Да, тоже что-то такое помню. Поменялось поведение счетчика.