# Динамическое обновление шапки сайта

Tags: дефект, поддержка, статус-так-задумано, очередь-проверок

Как можно видеть, SO стремится максимально быстро реагировать на появление новых вопросов/ответов, обновления существующих и т.д. Т.е. не нужно, в общем случае, вручную обновлять страницу, чтобы понять, что произошло какое-то изменение.

При этом замечено, что индикатор кол-ва правок не пропадает при окончании очереди правок. В этом есть какой-то скрытый смысл, сложность реализации или просто недосмотр? А может дело в браузере?

Картинку прилагаю:

> [image: Очередь кончилась, но шапка не обновилась]

На комментарий [@Grundy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3182/%d0%94%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0#comment10161_3182) у меня есть ещё одна картинка:

> [image: ожидает утверждения]

Такой вот хинт всплывает при одновременном отображении страницы "Очередь кончилась!". Одно явно противоречит другому.

**Обновление**

В предложенном как "дубликат" вопросе речь об "очереди правок меток" на "мете". В моем случае, речь о индикаторе "правок, ожидающих подтверждения" (когда юзер с репутацией <2000 предлагает изменение, и это изменение я могу утвердить). Более того, в [том вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/944/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B6%D1%83-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8) ничего не сказано о поведении счетчика при ручном обновлении страницы. Я же вижу счетчик до тех пор, пока принудительно не обновлю страницу (через `F5` например), т.е. иконка с числом не обновляется (не исчезает) без ручной перезагрузки страницы. Именно об этом говорит слово "Динамическое", использованное в заголовке вопроса. Например, при появлении новых входящих сообщений или достижений (иконки в левой части шапки) обновлять страницу вручную не требуется. Т.о. я не считаю свой вопрос дубликатом, предложенного @NicolasChabanovsky.

Comment: индикатор показывает _общее_ количество правок

Comment: @Grundy это звучит слишком обще. Нельзя ли по-конкретнее?

Comment: тут уже были вопросы про такое поведение счетчиков

Comment: @Grundy ссылку можете предоставить? По классическим канонам в таком случае надо мой вопрос помечать требующим закрытия :)

Comment: @Grundy я помню вопрос об учёте там **собственных** правок, которые система не даёт рассматривать (оно и понятно), но о том, что из счётчика не исчезают уже рассмотренные правки, по-моему, вопроса ещё не было.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поведение счетчика очереди одинаково [как для Меты](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/944/), так и для основного сайта. Индикатор отображает общее количество элементов в очереди проверки. Счетчик несет лишь информационную нагрузку. Не понятно на сколько необходимо обновлять его динамически.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понимаю систему правок, она ждёт подтверждения от **нескольких** человек. Правка осталась в очереди, потому что ещё не собрала достаточное количество подтверждений. Но в то же время системе нечего вам предложить, потому что вы то эту правку уже проверили.

Но это моя личная версия. Могу ошибаться.

Comment: Имхо, ошибочная версия, т.к. обновление страницы убирает иконку с цифрой очереди.

Comment: @alexolut То есть, ваш вопрос надо чуть-чуть изменить? "При окончании очереди правок индикатор кол-ва правок не пропадает, пока не обновишь страницу." Что я путаю?